# add Event listener to a specific Activity

Tags: android, events, event-handling

Upon receiving a GCM Intent in my GcmIntentService I am building a push notification and I have to set a specific Activity as EventListener.

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
        //This code gets triggered, what to add here 
        // to make SomeActivity's onEvent get triggered
    }
}


public interface EventListener {
    int onEvent(Event event);
}

public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements EventListener {

    @Override
    public int onEvent(Event event) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Register a broadcast receiver in the Activity

Answer (score 0):

Check these [Activity Listener - Google Cloud Messaging - BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311492/activity-listener-google-cloud-messaging-broadcastreceiver)
https://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html

Comment: I know this theory, thanks. The problem is I'm working on an existing App in which a previous programmer already implemented this "EventListener" structure. I'm trying to adhere to his style. If it's not possible, I have to reprogram it the "Android Way".